# NPE when trying to addElement() for a Vector

Tags: java, vector, nullpointerexception, element, addition

Here is part of my *Ownership* class. It gets no compile errors but when I attempt to run with my other classes, and put in the correct input, it gives me a NPE at the addElement() line of addOwner()...and I have no idea why. *OwnerParser* is not the problem, I know for sure, and neither is the input. I tried in a smaller project to initialize a Vector then list it's contents, and it gave me a NPE as well. Basically I need to know how to **add a new Owner object to the OwnerList without getting a NullPointerException** Thanks.

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Ownership implements Serializable
    {
        private Vector<Owner> ownerList;
        private Vector<Pet> petList;

        public void Ownership()
        {
            ownerList = new Vector<Owner>();
            petList = new Vector<Pet>();
        }

     public boolean addOwner(String b)
       {
       Owner r = new Owner();
       r = OwnerParser.parseStringToOwner(b);
       ownerList.addElement(r);
               return true;
       }
   }
```

Comment: When discussing exceptions, provide the stack trace pls. `Owner r` can be null, or `ownerList` can be `null` in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default "constructor" has a `void` return value, and is thus not a constructor but an ordinary method, named like a constructor. Consequently, the "constructor" is never called, and the vector is never initialized.

Change `public void Ownership() {...}` to `public Ownership() {...}` and it will work.

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot. It works just fine now. Double face palm for me